# Как мне настроить функцию в django?

Tags: django

начал изучать django по уроку https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLA0M1Bcd0w8... и дошел до урока 12, где нужно было подключить функции slug. у меня два проекта, в первом проекте ятупо все повторяю, то что он делает, а во втором я делаю уже по аналогии, меняю только текст, блоки и сам стиль сайта. Но столкнулся с проблемой во втором проекте, что блоки при нажатии на читать пост, он должен был открыть страницу с этим постом, а он, получается, просто отображается, в старой странице и при нажатии на читать пост он показывает на отсутствие страницы. где я мог упустить url? Вот мой код: https://github.com/David138it/david138it

[image: Как на данный момент выглядит пост]

[image: Какую ошибку показывает]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том что в файл models.py я вместо self.slug указал self.pk.Вот исправленный код:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post', kwargs={'post_slug':self.slug})
```